# TypeORM: How does TypeORM compare timestamps?

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, typeorm

I am using TypeORM to run this query:

```
SELECT "subagreementlog"."created_at" AS "subagreementlog_created_at" FROM "subagreement_logs" "subagreementlog" WHERE "subagreementlog"."subagreement_id" = $1 AND "subagreementlog"."created_at" > $2 LIMIT 1 -- PARAMETERS: ["0d71866e-3b78-4321-8ae8-dc39ffe82dbc","2020-11-12T13:57:16.618Z"]
```

I am looking for a record where the "created_at" value is greater than "2020-11-12T13:57:16.618Z" but this is actually returning the same value as if I was saying equal to or greater than.

```
result is: { subagreementlog_created_at: 2020-11-12T13:57:16.618Z }
```

Looking for guidance as to why this may be the case.

Also, here is the definition for said field in the Entity

```
@CreateDateColumn({ name: "created_at" })
@Field(_ => GraphQLISODateTime, {
  description: "Timestamp the subagreement was changed"
})
public createdAt!: Date;
```

Comment: Postgresql stores microseconds in timestamps. Can you check these in `subagreementlog.created_at`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried increasing your parameter value? For example, rather than

**2020-11-12T13:57:16.618Z** try **2020-11-12T13:57:17.618Z** (+1 second)

I believe you will still get a match even though the data is clearly before the parameter.

If you get a match I suspect what is happening is that you are storing data in one timezone (UTC likely) but using a local time for your parameter. I do not know TypeORM but maybe it converts timezones on reads and writes but does not convert parameters.

Just a guess but I hope it helps.